# error appears in jdeveloper 11g 11112

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

i need help on compiling my project in jdeveloper 11g.
previously my application (jsp+servlets) works smoothly in jdeveloper 10g with oc4j (deploys in WAR file).
but since i migrate to jdeveloper 11g, it appears several errors like this :

```
<Nov 27, 2009 1:13:50 PM WIT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1259302429721' for task '2'. Error is: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Nov 27, 2009 1:13:50 PM WIT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'TA_HelpDesk'.> 
<Nov 27, 2009 1:13:50 PM WIT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
[01:13:50 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[01:13:50 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application TA_HelpDesk due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[Application TA_HelpDesk stopped and undeployed from Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]
<Nov 27, 2009 1:16:55 PM WIT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1259302613288' for task '3'. Error is: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Nov 27, 2009 1:16:55 PM WIT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'helpdesk'.> 
<Nov 27, 2009 1:16:55 PM WIT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
 Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

and the error compile were :

```
Warning: <Nov 27, 2009 1:16:44 PM WIT> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160187> <weblogic.appc failed to compile your application. Recompile with the -verbose option for more details. Please see the error message(s) below.> 
Warning: There are 1 nested errors:
Warning: weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.ComplianceException: The element servlet-class, "helpdesk_project.CaptchaServiceSingleton" must be a subclass of "javax.servlet.Servlet".
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.BaseComplianceChecker.addDescriptorError(BaseComplianceChecker.java:74)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.BaseComplianceChecker.addDescriptorError(BaseComplianceChecker.java:80)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.BaseComplianceChecker.isClassAssignable(BaseComplianceChecker.java:149)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.ServletComplianceChecker.checkServlet(ServletComplianceChecker.java:104)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.ServletComplianceChecker.check(ServletComplianceChecker.java:42)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.internal.dd.compliance.ComplianceUtils.checkCompliance(ComplianceUtils.java:48)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspcInvoker.checkCompliance(JspcInvoker.java:145)
Warning:  at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspcInvoker.compile(JspcInvoker.java:198)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.AppcUtils.compileWAR(AppcUtils.java:377)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.WARModule.compile(WARModule.java:236)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleCompileFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleCompileFlow.java:18)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:37)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.run(FlowDriver.java:26)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.WARCompiler.compile(WARCompiler.java:29)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppCompilerFlow.compileInput(AppCompilerFlow.java:112)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppCompilerFlow.compile(AppCompilerFlow.java:37)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.runBody(Appc.java:200)
Warning:  at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
Warning:  at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
Warning:  at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.main(Appc.java:259)
Warning:  at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:14)
```

and then deployment process ends with incomplete status.
what should i do then?
thx a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing `oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum` on your classpath, hence the:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType
```

Add `${ORACLE_HOME}/dmt/oputil.jar` and/or `${ORACLE_HOME}/dmt/opreapi-batch.jar` on your classpath (not sure which one contain the missing class but they are often used together anyway).

Then, rerun appc as the second error (with `helpdesk_project.CaptchaServiceSingleton` might be related to the first issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems can not found this class:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.Enum$EnumType

Need to include above class also, you need to find a jar containing that class.