# What is the jar file for oracle.dmt.op.re.base.DataItem?

Tags: java

I tried to deploy a web app using ADF & BC by Jdev 11.1.1.1.0 & wls 10.3.1.0. The web app builds, but when I try to deploy the war file I get the following exception:

```
<Oct 24, 2011 10:37:44 AM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.DataItem
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dmt.op.re.base.DataItem
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:296)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:269)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

What is the jar file for oracle.dmt.op.re.base.DataItem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Weblogic domain the app is deployed on doesn't have the Application Development Runtime installed. Take a look at this guide for information on how to extend your current domain or create a new one to support ADF: [Upgrading an Oracle ADF Environment](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/upgrade.1111/e10127/upgrade_adf_env.htm).

Here is another guide that can help you configure your Weblogic server: [Extending WebLogic Server for ADF Applications](http://radalcove.com/blog/?p=34)

Alternatively, you can try to include the JAR's specified in this very similar question's answer: [error appears in jdeveloper 11g 11112](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1807128/851811). These jars are probably included in your JDeveloper version.

Comment: We went error appears in jdeveloper 11g 11112, we can't find jar file to download. Can you tell us how to download them ? Thx